# Unsupported media type error on POST request

Tags: java, spring-boot, http

I send a request to my backend application which runs on a Spring Boot, and get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

I send two parameters which are `id` and `key`and a body which is a `.jpg` image to the following code:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String uploadPicture(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id, @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
                            @RequestBody File picture) {
    final Picture picture1;
    picture1 = new Picture(id, name);

    service.addPicture(picture1);

    return "Picture added!";
}
```

Now I don't resend this picture to the DB from the code, but even this way I keep getting this error. I searched through the Net as well as through many questions on Stackoverflow, but all the other cases do not seem to solve my problem.
How can I rewrite my code to solve it?

Comment: Can you change the postmapping annotation to `@PostMapping(path= "/upload", consumes = "image/jpeg")`

Comment: @aksappy, I tried to do it this way, but the error is still here.

Comment: Can you show us the request you are sending?